# represent all levels of grouping factor with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

```
tnt <- data.frame( g = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), x = c(1:5,2:6), y = "things" ) 

library(plyr)
ddply(tnt, .(g,x), summarise, count = length(y) )
```

Considering the above code that is counting the number of rows for each `x` value in each `g` group:

What is the simplest way to have the level `6` represented in `a` and `1` represented in `b`? i.e. all levels of `x` represented in all levels of `g`.

My solution would be using `as.data.frame(table(x))` after resetting the levels for each `ddply` chunk to `1:6` but that seems cumbersome.

(I am not tied to using plyr if the simplest way involves base)

---

**EDIT**

The by @rrs answer is great (+1), however, it is my fault that in trying to create a easy example I over simplified the problem. There are many grouping factors (not just `g`) and When I try `.drop = FALSE` I get the following error:

> Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE

I think this might be because of many grouping factors that nevor occur together and never should.  How can I do the following:

```
c4 <- data.frame( g = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5),
                  f = c(sample(letters[24:25], 5, replace = TRUE),
                        sample(letters[25:26], 5, replace = TRUE)),
                  x = c(1:5,2:6), 
                  y = "things" )


ddply(c4, .(g,f,x), summarise, count = length(y), .drop = FALSE)
```

but the `.drop = FALSE` should only apply to `x` not `g` and `f` i.e. there should be no `z` in `a`.

Comment: You might need to rework the example in your edit. When I look at `c4` I see "z" and "a" together in rows 22, 24, 26, 28, and 30.

Comment: I ran your code in the edit, there's no row with a "z" and "a" together. Is there something else wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.drop = FALSE`:

```
ddply(tnt, .(g,x), summarise, count = length(y), .drop = FALSE)
```